# how to use 'selector gadget' to scrape data into R?

Tags: python, css, r, css-selectors, ipython

[image]I have managed to select the needed content from a website , using 'selector gadget' which helped create a 'css selector' . How could I export the content I selected into 'R'  or use the css selector generated for scraping the data off that website? Could anyone please guide me if at all you have an idea or experience in doing so. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You haven't included any specific details to make it possible to offer specific suggestions. It would be helpful if you at least show some code you are working with. Have you made any attempt to download a file or scrape any data from a web page in R? I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials that will pop up with a quick google search for the basics.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr FLick..   The url of the content is "http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/ht-seq" . I could not share code only because I did not write any code. . It was with a mouse that I selected certain content of a website I shall try to share a screen grab of the same, the resultant code was "" .sites-codesnippet-block "" this was the css selection I made.

Comment: I don't know R, but most languages have a CSS parsing library that you could use, with that selector, to extract text.  See Nokogiri in Ruby or beautifulsoup in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today I came across this web page which helps answer my own question perfectly with hands on tutorial .

http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

I hope it is of some use.

Thanks everyone for your timely suggestions and inputs.